# DBMS_STATS with Looping

Tags: oracle, plsql

I just tried to learn new things. I just make a experiment to analyze tables with looping. But, I found error that said

> 'Invalid reference to variable 'indx'

. If I take out the DBMS_STATS 'thing' and just to print the result, it works. But when I tried to analyze the tables, the error came out.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ANALYZE_TABLE
    AS
        CURSOR table_cur IS
            SELECT  TABLE_NAME
            FROM    ALL_TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'STUDENT%';

        table_nm table_cur%ROWTYPE;
        TYPE table_nms IS TABLE OF table_nm%TYPE;
        l_table  table_nms;
    BEGIN
        OPEN  table_cur;
        FETCH table_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_table;
        CLOSE table_cur;

        FOR indx IN 1..l_table.COUNT LOOP
            IF (indx.table_name = 'STUDENT_DETAILS') THEN 
        dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'ADMIN', tabname => indx.table_name , estimate_percent => 100, 
        method_opt => 'for all indexed columns size auto',
        degree => 4 ,cascade => TRUE );
            ELSIF (indx.table_name = 'STUDENT_ALLOWANCE' OR indx.table_name = 'STUDENT_PAYMENT') 
          THEN
            DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (ownname =>  'ADMIN', tabname => indx.table_name , estimate_percent => 100, 
        method_opt => 'for all indexed columns size auto',
        degree => 4 ,cascade => TRUE );
          ELSE
            DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (ownname =>  'ADMIN', tabname => indx.table_name , estimate_percent => 100, 
        method_opt => 'for all indexed columns size auto',
        degree => 4 ,cascade => TRUE );
          END IF;
            --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_table(indx).TABLE_NAME);
        END LOOP;
    END ANALYZE_TABLE;
```

Any suggestion? Or a better way to analyze tables with this loop?
Thank you in advance for anyone that helping me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the contents of your array, not the loop index. The loop index tells you which element in the array. So:

```
IF (l_table(indx).table_name = 'STUDENT_DETAILS') THEN
```

and so on

Comment: Very similar answer in the exact same moment.

Comment: wah thanks so much, btw is it possible if I want to make the analyze tables parallel? so they can be analyzed together, no need to wait until the other table is done analyzed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the values in your table as follows:

```
 if (l_table(indx).table_name = 'STUDENT_DETAILS') ...
```